# Solve dependency issue when using gRPC cpp in bazel

Tags: grpc, bazel

I am trying to run a simple program with gRPC in dependency. I tried several examples but continuesly get the following error:

```
ERROR: /home/git/examples/WORKSPACE:1:1: name 'git_repository' is not defined
ERROR: Error evaluating WORKSPACE file
```

This is my bazel version:

```
➜ git:(master) ✗ bazel version
Build label: 0.23.2
```

And this is the workspace file content:

```
git_repository(
    name = "com_github_grpc_grpc",
    commit = "ac0808b107d73613191b66617a547a201871a845",
    remote = "https://github.com/grpc/grpc.git",
)

load("@com_github_grpc_grpc//:bazel/grpc_deps.bzl", "grpc_deps")

grpc_deps()

bind(
    name = "grpc_cpp_plugin",
    actual = "@com_github_grpc_grpc//:grpc_cpp_plugin",
)

bind(
    name = "grpc++_codegen_proto",
    actual = "@com_github_grpc_grpc//:grpc++_codegen_proto",
)
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`git_repository` is no longer a native rule. You need to include it at the top of your `WORKSPACE` with:

```py
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository")
```