# Pull Git Repository using Bazel returns git_repository is not defined

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to build my project running Bazelbuild //... but I'm getting the following error

> CPTI/WORKSPACE:1:1: name 'git_repository' is not defined

There's my `WORKSPACE` file:

```
git_repository(
  name = "org_pubref_rules_protobuf",
  remote = "https://github.com/pubref/rules_protobuf",
  tag = "v0.8.1",
#  commit = "d9523f3d443b6a4f3fabc72051d84eb5474d7745"
)

load("@org_pubref_rules_protobuf//cpp:rules.bzl", "cpp_proto_repositories")
#cpp_proto_repositories()

#BTW, @org_pubref_rules_protobuf already contains @com_google_googletest

load("//tools/build_defs:externals.bzl",
  "new_patched_http_archive",
)

# The sparsehash BUILD is copied from https://github.com/livegrep/livegrep
new_patched_http_archive(
  name = "com_github_sparsehash",
  url = "https://github.com/sparsehash/sparsehash/archive/sparsehash-2.0.3.tar.gz",
  sha256 = "05e986a5c7327796dad742182b2d10805a8d4f511ad090da0490f146c1ff7a8c",
  build_file = "//third_party:BUILD.sparsehash",
  strip_prefix = "sparsehash-sparsehash-2.0.3/",
  patch_file = "//third_party:sparsehash.patch",
)
```

Comment: Is that the full WORKSPACE file, or just a snippet?

Answer (score 3):

I found another post with the answer [Solve dependency issue when using gRPC cpp in bazel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55190124/solve-dependency-issue-when-using-grpc-cpp-in-bazel)

I added and it worked. Sorry, I didn't found it before.

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository")
```